# Undestanding the output of route -n

Tags: linux, route

Can someone explain me what the out put of `route -n`?

```
# route -n 
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: `man route` is all you need.

Comment: `route` is deprecated on linux, use `ip route` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Your table is basically saying:

If you want to reach another host with an IP address

- starting with 192.168.0 -> send it to interface `eth1`
- starting with 169.254 -> send it to interface `eth1`
- starting with 127 -> send it to interface `lo`
- else send it to your router (192.168.0.1)

The `route` command is a legacy command you should use the [iproute tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) instead.

For a more basic introduction you can start with the Wikipedia article about [Routing Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table).

Comment: Hey @michas thanks by the explanation, what I'm trying to achieve is a load balance on opensuse 12.3, I got two internet connection one is from my shared building internet, it's pluged to a router on port WAN and I'm connected to the router with eth0 pluged at port LAN1, the other is my own internet cable it's pluged on a router wifi and it's  connected with wlan0 and I got a 3rd one That I intent to use for my local Lan, which will be available for the other devices at my home, this is eth1 pluged to another router. I want all that Local Lan to go through a proxy squid.

Comment: 'route command is a legacy command', according to who?

Comment: This answer would be more comprehensible to a beginner if it (1) explained the meaning of gateway, (2) explained what a 0.0.0.0  gateway means and (3) explained that the network packet filtering by the initial part of the IP address is done by combining the destination and genmask fields in the output and (4) explained what the G flag means in the output